# How to setCustomValidity when username is less than 4 characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this simple html and Jquery code. I want to set the setCustomValidity to appear when user inputs 4 characters in the textfield. So far I'm not getting such result in my code:

```
<html>
<body>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter username')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" id="username" name="username"" required>

</body>
<script>
    var username = $("#username").val();

    if (username.strlen < 4) {
        username.setCustomValidity('Username must contain at least 5 characters');
    } else {
        username.setCustomValidity('');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#username").keyup(checkUsername);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

I tried this:

```
<script>
    var username = $("#username").val();

    if (username.strlen < 4) {
        username.setCustomValidity('Username must contain at least 5 characters');
    } else {
        username.setCustomValidity('');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#username").keyup(checkUsername);
    });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

friend why you are not using html5 pattern like

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username"  pattern=".{5,}" title="Username must contain at least 5 characters" required id="username" name="username">
```

**Note : Now user cant able to enter less than 5 character in user text field**

Demo:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="youractionpage.php">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username"  pattern=".{5,}" title="Username must contain at least 5 characters" required id="username" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: dont worry brother  i am using chrome its work fine html5 works fine with all latest browsers  :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as `strlen` method in string. You may want to use `length`.

Sooo it should be....

```
if (username.length <= 4)
```

I'm not sure if its `<=` or `=` for your message is contradicting with your title. I mean this one. `Username must contain at least 5 characters` but title is `username is less than 4 characters`.